# Blazor Server Side AllowAnonymousToFolder

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, blazor

I have added Azure AD authentication so that all requests to the application has to login. But I would like to seperate this since I have a "Public" and "Private" folder for my pages.

I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0 which is what I need, but once I go to a page in the public folder, I still get prompted to login.

Expected result: All the pages in the /Pages/Public folder will not prompt login.

Result: When navigationg to a page in the /Pages/Public folder Im prompted with a login request.

Im relatively new at Server side Blazor and Net Core so its very possible that Im missunderstanding something or that this functionality isnt available for Blazor. If so then might I get a hint to what to look at instead?

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
{
      Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options);
      options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
      options.Events.OnTokenValidated += OnTokenValidatedFunc;
});
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
     //No error here but no effect either
     options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Pages/Public");
}).AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
     var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                      .Build();
     options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Comment: "...but I cant seem to get it to work.. " Can you please be more specific? What is the desired behavior, what is the current behavior? Do you get any errors or warnings? What did you try?

Comment: @JHBonarius Edited my question. Im expecting to not be prompted to login, allowing me to be anonymous. Instead, Im prompted to login.

Comment: Is anonymous authentication enabled? (or accidentally disabled?). Are you serving Razor Pages or Razor Components (Blazor)? Did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/)?

Comment: Im not sure about the Anonymous authentication, This application has not accepted anonymous before and always redirected to login. I have read that, but it seems to focus on AuthorizeView for showing and hiding components? What I want is:
- Two folders with razor components, one folder for Anonymous, and one folder for Logged in. And if a user tries to access a Logged In component without being logged in, they should be redirected to the login page.

If I set @attribute [AllowAnonymous] in the _Host file then all becomes Anonymous. But it feels like more of a hack then solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "Whatever")]` in a new `_Imports.razor` in the folder with all the pages which require Auth. This will add the Authorize attribute to all pages in that folder and below. You will have to remove your global Auth. requirement though.

Comment: Ive created a policy and added the attribute and it works well. Whats still left is how to get the same behaviour as before, that instead of just printing out "Not authorized", I would like it to redirect to the Azure login screen. If Im correct, then my first codeblock in my example code is the one redirecting, but It does not seem to run with this Authorize method.
The policy is added with AddPolicy("IsDeveloper", policy => policy
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                 .Build());

Comment: So I think the issue here is that by not using the default AddAuthentication in startup.cs, Im not getting the login redirect for free, and have to make my own. I would much prefer to have the standard login and just have a couple of pages Anonymous instead. But it does not seem to exist [AllowAnonymous] attribute in Blazor? Know of a best practise method of simulating this in?